# Explain not showing memory usage

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to see how much memory a query takes.  In articles I can see in their `explain` output has a memory value but when I run explain I do not get a memory value.

Here is my query:

```sql
explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select * from watched_url_queue
join rate_check rc on watched_url_queue.domain_key = rc.domain_key
where rc.locked = false
order by rc.domain_key
limit 1;
```

And this is my output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.70..0.85 rows=1 width=336) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: watched_url_queue.watched_url_record_id, watched_url_queue.url, watched_url_queue.domain_key, watched_url_queue.targets, watched_url_queue.create_date, watched_url_queue.tries, watched_url_queue.defer_until, watched_url_queue.duration, watched_url_queue.user_auth_custom_id, watched_url_queue.completed, rc.domain_key, rc.last_scan, rc.locked, rc.domain_key
  Buffers: shared hit=7
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.70..32514.53 rows=219864 width=336) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: watched_url_queue.watched_url_record_id, watched_url_queue.url, watched_url_queue.domain_key, watched_url_queue.targets, watched_url_queue.create_date, watched_url_queue.tries, watched_url_queue.defer_until, watched_url_queue.duration, watched_url_queue.user_auth_custom_id, watched_url_queue.completed, rc.domain_key, rc.last_scan, rc.locked, rc.domain_key
        Inner Unique: true
        Merge Cond: (watched_url_queue.domain_key = rc.domain_key)
        Buffers: shared hit=7
        ->  Index Scan using idx_watchedurlqueue_domainkey on public.watched_url_queue  (cost=0.42..29069.88 rows=439728 width=289) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: watched_url_queue.watched_url_record_id, watched_url_queue.url, watched_url_queue.domain_key, watched_url_queue.targets, watched_url_queue.create_date, watched_url_queue.tries, watched_url_queue.defer_until, watched_url_queue.duration, watched_url_queue.user_auth_custom_id, watched_url_queue.completed
              Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Index Scan using rate_check_pkey on public.rate_check rc  (cost=0.28..141.85 rows=2519 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: rc.domain_key, rc.last_scan, rc.locked
              Filter: (NOT rc.locked)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 0.362 ms
Execution time: 0.060 ms
```

How do I see the memory usage?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` shows the memory usage `Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 823kB`.

Comment: In the query I put in my question it is using `explain analyze` but no memory is shown in output also pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Merge Join doesn't report memory usage because it doesn't need any buffers (like e.g. the hash join). It simply goes through the sorted data from the two indexes as they are retrieved without the need to buffer that.

If you want to estimate the overall size of each step in the plan, you can multiply the `width` value and the `rows` value (from the actual rows).

But that is not necessarily the "memory" that is needed by the query, as the blocks are managed in the shared memory ("cache") rather then "by the query".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How would you go about turning the width*rows into a memory amount?  I am trying to figure out how much worker mem I need on a distributed app

Comment: `width` is the "size of the rows in byte" so the result of `width * rows` is the memory amount (in bytes). If no memory is reported, you don't need `work_mem` for that query. For large results `temp_buffers` might be important if intermediate results need to be stored on disk.

Comment: Ah very interesting!  Thanks for the help